# How can I host a web service that can be used on browser, Android and iOS by users sharing a same database on cloud?

Tags: android, ios, web-services, hosting, iot

I am doing a project on the attendance system inside a school. A website, hosted on cloud, will be used to save the attendance records. Android and iOS apps could access to the same cloud and get the updated information on time.
To do this, I found some sloutions like Flutter from Google and NodeJS.

I had tried doing the Django web app and NodeJS. But hosted Django app doesn't work well on Android and iOS but on Browser.

What I am looking for is a development framework which can be used on Android, iOS and web browser. So, if I change code, the changes happen to all those three platforms.

Basically, it is an IoT project. So, I would like to get your opinions on how should I develop this and what development platform or language should I use?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a service that allows you to get attendance on the 3 platforms you listed, you could achieve that with just a web application. Using a front-end framework you could layout the site to look differently on a computer and on mobile devices. This would probably be the easiest way to achieve literally one codebase.

If you want to have an app for iOS Android and the web then you could probably take a look at React. You could use Node.js as your backend, React.js for web and React Native for iOS and Android.

Flutter also works but flutter web is kinda new so there might not be as much documentation out there for the web part.

Depending on how long you have to develop this I think the first option would be the better choice if you have a very limited time

Comment: Great advice! Thank you 